# Hide(); will not hide the map images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-11, show-hide

I have a problem hiding the map images using `hide();` method and it works on browsers such as Chrome, FF, Safari, and Edge except for IE11.

I read other similar problems saying something like IE11 doesn't like hide/show(). I tried this method `$(".mapActive").css({'display':'none'});` and it works OK on all browsers except IE11.

It doesn't work on IE11 - 
[image]

This works on Chrome, FF, Safari, and Edge
[image]

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
$(".mapActive").hide();
$("ul.j_linkLocation li#mapTX").addClass("active").show(); 
$(".mapActive#mapTX").show();
$("ul.j_linkLocation li").click(function() {
$("ul.j_linkLocation li").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$(".mapActive").hide();
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast');
  return false;
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row m_activeMap">
            <div class="col-lg col-map-width">
                <div class="j_img-overlay"><img src="imgs/img-overlay.png" alt="Seek the World! | SVRS" id="imghide"></div>
                <div class="j_map-interfaces">
                    <div id="mapTX" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-TX.png" alt="Seek the World - Texas" class="m_map"></div>
                    <div id="mapLA" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-LA.png" alt="Seek the World - Louisiana" class="m_map"></div>
                    <div id="mapMI" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-MI.png" alt="Seek the World - Mississippi" class="m_map"></div>
                    <div id="mapAL" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-AL.png" alt="Seek the World - Alabama" class="m_map"></div>
                    <div id="mapGA" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-GA.png" alt="Seek the World - Georgia" class="m_map"></div>
                    <div id="mapFL" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-FL.png" alt="Seek the World - Florida" class="m_map"></div>
                    <!--<div id="mapSC" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-SC.png" alt="Seek the World - South Carolina" class="m_map"></div>
                    <div id="mapNC" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-NC.png" alt="Seek the World - North Carolina" class="m_map"></div>
                    <div id="mapVA" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-VA.png" alt="Seek the World - Virginia" class="m_map"></div>-->
                    <div id="mapMD" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-MD.png" alt="Seek the World - Maryland" class="m_map"></div>
                    <!--<div id="mapWV" class="mapActive"><img src="imgs/map-WV.png" alt="Seek the World - West Virginia" class="m_map"></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="j_linkHeader"><img src="imgs/link-header.png" alt="Seek the location below!"></div>
                <div class="j_linkHeader2"><p>Seek the location below!</p></div>
                <div id="j_mapLinks" class="j_linksCol">
                    <ul class="j_linkLocation">
                        <li class="j_linkHover is-active">
                            <a href="#mapTX" class="j_linkThumb"> Austin, TX</a>
                            <p class="j_accordion-panel">Texas School for the Deaf<br>1234 Congress Ave, <br>Austin, TX 78753<br>
                            <span class="j_dateLocation">Feb 7, 2018</span></p>
                        </li>

                        <li class="j_linkHover">
                            <a href="#mapLA" class="j_linkThumb"> Baton Rouge, LA</a>
                            <p class="j_accordion-panel">Rouge School for the Deaf<br>1234 Easy Ave, <br>Baton Rouge, LA 68753<br>
                            <span class="j_dateLocation">Feb 18, 2018</span></p>
                        </li>

                        <li class="j_linkHover">
                            <a href="#mapMI" class="j_linkThumb"> Jackson, MI</a>
                            <p class="j_accordion-panel">School for the Deaf<br>1234 NoWay Ave, <br>Jackson, MI 58753<br>
                            <span class="j_dateLocation">Feb 18, 2018</span></p>
                        </li>   

                        <li class="j_linkHover">
                            <a href="#mapAL" class="j_linkThumb"> Talladega, AL</a>
                            <p class="j_accordion-panel">Mobile for the Deaf<br>1234 Whoo Ave, <br>Talladega, AL 48753<br>
                            <span class="j_dateLocation">Feb 25, 2018</span></p>
                        </li>

                        <li class="column-break"></li>

                        <li class="j_linkHover">
                            <a href="#mapFL" class="j_linkThumb"> St Augustine, FL</a>
                            <p class="j_accordion-panel"> Florida School for the Deaf<br>1234 Ouch Ave, <br> St Augustine, FL 48753<br>
                            <span class="j_dateLocation">Mar 12, 2018</span></p>
                        </li>   

                        <li class="j_linkHover">
                            <a href="#mapGA" class="j_linkThumb"> Atlanta, GA</a>
                            <p class="j_accordion-panel">Atlanta for the Deaf<br>1234 You Ave, <br>Atlanta, GA 38753<br>
                            <span class="j_dateLocation">Mar 12, 2018</span></p>
                        </li>   

                        <li class="j_linkHover">
                            <a href="#mapMD" class="j_linkThumb"> Frederick, MD</a>
                            <p class="j_accordion-panel">Frederick for the Deaf<br>1234 You Ave, <br>Frederick, MD 38753<br>
                            <span class="j_dateLocation">Mar 12, 2018</span></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the only issue I have before I deliver the project to the client.

Comment: Please **don't** force us to visit broken links or links that might go down in the future. Create a [mcve] instead.

Comment: $('#item').css({'display':'block'}, should work, your link doesnt work, i get a time out

Comment: The link doesnt work? I clicked on it and it shows the website I worked on.

Comment: @Grumpy - where did you get that `#item` from?

Comment: Post the html code please

Comment: replace #item with .mapActive

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `"use strict";` in IE browsers.

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
  // "use strict"; // IE hates this, we hate IE

  var $locLI = $("ul.j_linkLocation").find("li"); // Cache! Think about performance
  var $mapActive = $(".mapActive");

  $mapActive.hide();

  $("#mapTX").addClass("active").show(); // No need to prefix with classes. ID is unique.

  $locLI.click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Use this instead of return false;

    $locLI.not( this ).removeClass("active"); // not this
    $(this).addClass("active");               // Now, this :)
    $mapActive.hide();                        // Hide again?.. hmm
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast');

  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but your codes doesn't work. It still will not hide the map images.

Answer (score 0):

Just learned that my co-worker had a newer version of IE11 (v11.8) browser and all of the map images were hidden and it works, but it didnt work on an older version. I have IE11 (v11.2). I was unable to find a link to update IE11 for Wins 10. They only have one for Wins 8 & 9. Oh well...